# Restore from __pycache__

Tags: python

I made a huge mistake and included a python file in a large group of files that I removed with -rm. However, I still have the .pyc file stored in `__pycache__`.

Is there any way to restore a python file from it's cache?

Answer (score 5):

Sorry to hear, try your luck with these Python byte-code de-compilers:

1. https://github.com/wibiti/uncompyle2
2. https://pypi.python.org/pypi/uncompyle6
3. https://sourceforge.net/projects/easypythondecompiler/files/
4. https://github.com/zrax/pycdc

Comment: I have tried uncompyle6 and worked like a charm! thank you very much